# Don't understand this keyword Call Method in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm a newbie and trying to understand the code :d
I have a piece of code check OS to choose the driver for browser:

```
 Open Browser To Login Page
    [Arguments]  ${url}
    ${system}=    Evaluate    platform.system()    platform
    Log   I am running on ${system}
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --window-size\=1920,1080
    Call Method    ${options}   add_experimental_option  useAutomationExtension  ${False}
    Run Keyword If  '${system}'=='Linux'    Run Keywords
    ...         Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    test-type
    ...    AND  Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    ignore-certificate-errors
    ...    AND  Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --disable-extensions
    ...    AND  Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --disable-gpu
    ...    AND  Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --no-sandbox
    ...    AND  Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --headless
    ${driver_path}=     Run Keyword If  '${system}'=='Linux'    Set Variable   /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
    ...     ELSE    Set Variable   ${windriver}
    Log To Console  driver_path:    ${driver_path}
    ${kwargs}=  BuiltIn.Create Dictionary  executable_path=${driver_path}
    Create Webdriver  Chrome  chrome_options=${options}    executable_path=${driver_path}
    Go To   ${web_url}
```

- In the section below, the "Call Method" keyword can call multiple times to be able to add more parameters into a ${options} variable? So, that ${options} variable can contain parameters? I have not imagined what the format will look like after being assigned a lot of arguments? Please help me explain this section.

> ```
> Run Keyword If  '${system}'=='Linux'    Run Keywords
>             ...         Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    test-type
>             ...    AND  Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    ignore-certificate-errors
>             ...    AND  Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --disable-extensions
>             ...    AND  Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --disable-gpu
>             ...    AND  Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --no-sandbox
>             ...    AND  Call Method    ${options}   add_argument    --headless
> ```

---

- In the section 2 below, I don't understand ${kwargs} variable name stands for what?, why must it use "BuiltIn." and why create a dictionary for the path?

> ${kwargs}=  BuiltIn.Create Dictionary  executable_path=${driver_path}

Comment: Making sense of existing code you do not understand is not within the spirit of [so]. In addition you are asking for help on multiple topics in the same question which in itself is against the question guidelines. In general when you have an issue, reduce it to a few lines by removing everything else. That way you'll learn the most and allows those that want to help to help you concretely without investing significant amount of time replicating your issue. .

Comment: @A.Kootstra thank you for reminding :)